# What is the correct HTTP Response to send in case of bad DNS Redirection?

Tags: java, http, jakarta-ee, dns, jersey

I've got a server hosting multiple websites. Server is written in Java+Jersey.
If someone makes his DNS point to my service, but this DNS doesn't match any of my hosted websites, what should I answer? Note that I need to do this programmatically and can't rely on some customization of my Web container ( Tomcat ) .

The problem is, if I display a « website not found » page, I shall have search engines reference my primary domain website under a false name, therefore downgrading its page rank because of someone else's mistake.

I tried to change my /etc/hosts file to reproduce the behaviour but can't guess what other websites are doing in this case too.

Any idea ? A simple 404 seems too light ? Bad Request seems inappropriate ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely a 4xx, since the error comes from the request (the `Host` header contains an invalid value).

I would say 404, Not found is probably the best answer here. This will prevent indexing from search engines.

Another solution could be to redirect (permanently) to the main domain of your website? I have seen this behaviour a few times.

Answer (score 1):

If you really don't want 404, 403 looks like it might be what you want. From RFC 2616:

> The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.

Answer (score 1):

Not really answering your question but the comment was too involved.  Here are some thoughts:

- If you show a "website has moved" message for someone else's URL then that will not affect your other domains in any manner.  The spiders should not attribute the content to your domain nor change your link ranking.
- I don't think there is any way for you to "downgrade" your page rank -- ever.  Either you have a link to your content or not.  [Pagerank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank) is a measurement of the inbound links only -- there is no way to have a "bad" link in terms of Pagerank.
- If you want to *benefit* from their bad DNS then I would just redirect them to your homepage with a proper host name.  That's what I do on my webserver if I get a hostname that doesn't match my domain *exactly*.

Hope this helps somewhat.